# How to scroll Panel by keyboard?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, scroll, panel

Inside a form, I have a `Panel` that contains a single `PictureBox` and nothing else. One of the requirements is that the user should be able to scroll through the contents of that panel by using only the keyboard. In other words, they would first need to tab into the panel and then use the Up/Down or PageUp/PageDown keys to scroll.

According to the Microsoft Docs,

> The TabStop property has no effect on the Panel control as it is a
>   container object.

Which, after trying it out appears to be very true. It's similar when looking up a TabStop property for the PictureBox, where it just says

> This property is not relevant for this class.

I tried adding a `VScrollBar` to the panel and setting its `TabStop` to `True`, but that didn't seem to do anything.

What is the best way to achieve the desired effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can derive from `Panel` and make it `Selectable` and set its `TabStop` to true. Then It's enough to override `ProcessCmdKey` and handle arrow keys to scroll. Don't forget to set its `AutoScroll` to true as well.

**Selectable Panel - Scrollable by Keyboard**

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
class SelectablePanel : Panel
{
    const int ScrollSmallChange = 10;
    public SelectablePanel()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserMouse, true);
        TabStop = true;
    }
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if (!Focused)
            return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);

        var p = AutoScrollPosition;
        switch (keyData)
        {
            case Keys.Left:
                AutoScrollPosition = new Point(-ScrollSmallChange - p.X, -p.Y);
                return true;
            case Keys.Right:
                AutoScrollPosition = new Point(ScrollSmallChange - p.X, -p.Y);
                return true;
            case Keys.Up:
                AutoScrollPosition = new Point(-p.X, -ScrollSmallChange - p.Y);
                return true;
            case Keys.Down:
                AutoScrollPosition = new Point(-p.X, ScrollSmallChange - p.Y);
                return true;
            default:
                return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was about to post an answer on this :) With a slight difference: overriding `ProcessCmdKey` of the Form, you don't need a custom control. It's possible to use the Panel's scrollbar: (e.g., `var scrollBar = panel1.VerticalScroll;`) and move the scrollbar setting its `.Value` property to `[X, Y] +- [SmallChange, LargeChange]`.

Comment: @Jimi  There are some points: •The panel is not selectable, you first need a way to select it. •The form also may contain a couple of controls and arrows keys have specific meanings to some controls like buttons. That's why I prefer to derive from panel and make it selectable and embed the scroll logic inside the derived panel.

Comment: Well, sure, I was about to do the same thing. Since you already posted an answer, I commented an alternative. Of course, it implies that the cursor keys are used just for scrolling the Panel (if you don't care to make the code a bit more complex).

Comment: @Jimi Thanks for the feedback. I added `if (!Focused) return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);` to let the probable child controls use their own key handling, in case the `Panel` is not focused.

Comment: Good solution :) Out of curiosity, why did you set `ControlStyles.UserMouse` here? Isn't `ControlStyles.Selectable` enough to let the Panel scroll using the mouse wheel?

Comment: @Jimi Setting `UserMouse` is to make it selectable using mouse.

Comment: Yes, that's why I asked. Since the Panel has already `ControlStyles.StandardClick` enabled, I usually add just `ControlStyles.Selectable` and you can select it with a mouse anyway. But it's nothing important. Thanks.

Comment: @Jimi but if you don't set `UserMouse` to true, clicking the panel will not select it. :/ Do you have a different observation when you try?

Comment: Yep, my mistake. I should have looked at the code of the custom *selectable* Panel I use. I forgot it has an override of `OnMouseDown` where it captures the Focus. I don't remember why I opted for this over the `UserMouse` style. There are other *Captures* in place for other reasons. Probably because it was redundant, at this point.

Comment: @Andii I assume you can use http://converter.telerik.com/ yourself. Let me know if you have any problem converting it to VB.NET

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry for my late reply. I had to experiment a bit (I don't have much experience with deriving controls) and have now successfully swapped the Panel with the SelectablePanel without any compile errors. But when I run and test it, it seems like nothing has changed. I can't set focus on the panel, not with the keyboard and not with the mouse either. I thought the tab order might be wrong, but I checked it and cycled through multiple times, and that doesn't seem to be it. Any ideas?

Comment: Just make sure `TabStop` is true, then you can focus by tab. You can also always focus with mouse.

Comment: You can first try to test it in a clean form. Make sure it's working (it will work, I've already tested.) Then try to fox the problem in the existing environment that you have.

Comment: Right, sorry for the confusion. The project is a dll and was set up to launch another application which then loads the dll, and apparently it was loading the wrong version from another location, so I'll have to look into that. After getting it to work another way (and remembering that I forgot to set `AutoScroll = True`), it now works like a charm, thanks!