# How to make TableLayoutPanel focusable

Tags: c#, winforms, containers, focus

I have a custom control that is derived from TableLayoutPanel. I want to make it focusable, but TableLayoutPanel is not. How can I do that? If I can't make a Control derived from TableLayoutPanel focusable itself, how can I work around it?

In the example below I have just added a TableLayoutPanel directly in order to show that tabbing through the form focuses the two ComboBoxes, but not my TableLayoutPanel based control. In this case it has button functionality, which is of course trivial and would rather be replaced by the existing Button control in a real world application, but it is for demonstration purposes only.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestCustomComboBox
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Description of MainForm.
    /// </summary>
    public class MainForm : Form
    {
        ComboBox comboBox1;
        ComboBox comboBox2;
        TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel1;
        Label label1;

        public MainForm()
        {
            comboBox1 = new ComboBox();
            comboBox2 = new ComboBox();
            tableLayoutPanel1 = new TableLayoutPanel();
            label1 = new Label();
            tableLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();
            SuspendLayout();

            comboBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;
            comboBox1.Location = new Point(82, 45);
            comboBox1.Name = "comboBox1";
            comboBox1.Size = new Size(121, 21);
            comboBox1.TabIndex = 0;

            comboBox2.FormattingEnabled = true;
            comboBox2.Location = new Point(96, 99);
            comboBox2.Name = "comboBox2";
            comboBox2.Size = new Size(121, 21);
            comboBox2.TabIndex = 1;

            tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = 1;
            tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100F));
            tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 20F));
            tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(label1, 0, 0);
            tableLayoutPanel1.Location = new Point(45, 149);
            tableLayoutPanel1.Name = "tableLayoutPanel1";
            tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 1;
            tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100F));
            tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 20F));
            tableLayoutPanel1.Size = new Size(200, 25);
            tableLayoutPanel1.TabIndex = 2;

            label1.AutoEllipsis = true;
            label1.BackColor = SystemColors.Window;
            label1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            label1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            label1.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            label1.Margin = new Padding(0);
            label1.Name = "label1";
            label1.Size = new Size(200, 100);
            label1.TabIndex = 0;
            label1.Text = "This is a placeholder for my own control";
            label1.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
            label1.Click += justToShowThatThisIsAControl;

            StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            AutoScaleDimensions = new SizeF(6F, 13F);
            AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.Font;
            ClientSize = new Size(284, 261);
            Controls.Add(tableLayoutPanel1);
            Controls.Add(comboBox2);
            Controls.Add(comboBox1);
            Name = "MainForm";
            Text = "TestCustomComboBox";
            tableLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout(false);
            ResumeLayout(false);
        }

        void justToShowThatThisIsAControl(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Boo");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As a custom control: `this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserMouse | ControlStyles.Selectable, true);` (in its constructor)

Comment: @Jimi: why do I need UserMouse? I have tried Selectable only and it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: To make it selectable (have the `Focus`) also by clicking it with a Mouse.

Comment: Set `this.TabStop = true;`, in case you need it, after setting the Styles.

Comment: Btw, your comment about `UserMouse` felt like a deja-vue. See this Reza Aghaei's answer (same thing): [How to scroll Panel by keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55105713/7444103).

Comment: I am sorry but it happens to me all too often that I search like mad and after finally having decided to post a question I find lots of answers elsewhere. Don't know what law of nature causes this ;-)